# Sku Title in Magento product view page

Tags: magento-1.9

I have inserted this the below code into the view.phtml page and although the sku code shows I need to show the SKU TITLE like this **SKU:**2828838 as opposed to just the code itself 2828838

```
<div class="std">
    <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getSku()), 'sku') ?>
 </div>
```

Comment: add the word "SKU" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
<div class="std">
    <strong><?php echo $this->__('SKU:')?></strong>
    <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getSku()), 'sku') ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank a mil Marius that's worked great! cheers

Comment: @Leon. If this solved your issue, mark it as accepted. Let's keep this website clean.